# Iterating over the strings within a Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

Example of the dataframe:

| ObjectTitle | ObjectCreationDate | ObjectCreator | ImageURL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "pot" | "1880" | Anonymous | NaN |
| "Vase" | "-770" | Anonymous | NaN |
| "Vase2" | "NaN" | Anonymous | NaN |
| "Table" | "1900-05-03" | Anonymous | NaN |
| "Table2" | "-300-12-01" | Anonymous | NaN |
| "pot2" | "1500-05" | Anonymous | NaN |

Everything is a string and I want the dates to become integers so I can work with them. I only need the years. I can't transform them to datetime because the years go below zero. And I can't replace the '-' with something else because then the years before zero also get replaced.

In Python I tried to iterate over every row in that column and then iterate over the elements of the string within that row starting from the second element, searching for a '-'. This way I can do something like delete everything after the first occurrence of the '-' or replace those with a '#' so I can split it afterwards.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    for element in df.loc[i,'ObjectCreationDate'][1:]:
        element.replace('-','#')
```

But this doesn't work because I get a key error: 0 I think my second line is faulty but I don't know why.

After the tip of AKX I tried this

```
def fix_date(string):
    if string.startswith('-'):
        return string.replace('-', '#',1) 
    return string
df['objectCreationDate'] = df['objectCreationDate'].apply(fix_date)
```

And this worked! Now I can try and split after '-'

Comment: It's always a good idea to add some data example, it makes the question self-explanatory

Comment: You are right, I put an example of the dataframe on top, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, when you find yourself doing a for loop over a dataframe, you're doing something wrong. You can just [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply) transformations to columns en masse.

I'm not sure I'm quite catching the logic of what you want, but this template might help you along.

```
def fix_date(val):
    # Do something with `val` here..?
    if val.startswith('-'):
        return "something else"
    return val
df['columnname_with_dates_as_strings'] = df['columnname_with_dates_as_strings'].apply(fix_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
row = df.iloc[i]
dates_as_strings = row['columnname_with_dates_as_strings'].split()
```

Comment: This doesn't work because I can not split them before I replace some of the '-' with something else (because for the years below zero, there is also a '-' sign that I do still need)

Comment: The main point was to answer your: "keyerror: 0 I think my second line is faulty but I dont know why" dataframe.loc[X] will use the indexing of the dataframe e.g. X in range ObjectTitles while dataframe.iloc[X] will use the row count (X in range row_count).

Comment: On the other hand, the split() part i have added due to "itterating over the strings within a Pandas column" and the fact that you had no example, so i thought it was a column where an item could be "YYYY-MM-DD YYYY-MM-DD ..." so you would have needed to split by empty space.